# Strategy pattern - DRY way to define methods used in some, but not all, child strategies

Tags: ruby, strategy-pattern

I am implementing a Strategy pattern in my Ruby project but running into a slight code style problem.

Let's say I have three strategy classes that inherit from a common base strategy class. Two of those three strategies will need access to a method - the third does not use it. So my instinct is to place the common method in the `Base` strategy:

```
class FoodStrategies::Base
  # Used by 2 of the 3 child strategy classes
  def add_hot_sauce
    puts "Food is now spicy"
  end

  def eat
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

class FoodStrategies::Taco < FoodStrategies::Base
  def eat
    add_hot_sauce
    puts "Spicy and delicious!"
  end
end

class FoodStrategies::Burrito < FoodStrategies::Base
  def eat
    add_hot_sauce
    puts "Spicy and tasty!"
  end
end

class FoodStrategies::Cereal < FoodStrategies::Base
  def eat
    puts "Yum"
  end
end
```

Technically this means `FoodStrategies::Cereal` will also have the `add_hot_sauce` method, but doesn't use it. This seems like a code smell to me. So I wonder if there is a more appropriate way to keep things DRY without supplying methods to strategies that aren't meant to use them.

I've tried googling around to see what others have done in this sort of situation, but surprisingly I haven't found anything. I also had the idea to add another layer of inheritance to these strategies, and place the method in that new inheritance layer:

```
class FoodStrategies::SpicyFood < FoodStrategies::Base
  def add_hot_sauce
    puts "Food is now spicy"
  end
end

class FoodStrategies::SpicyFood::Taco < FoodStrategies::Base
  # etc.
end
```

This would let me isolate the desired behavior only to children of `SpicyFood`, meaning `Taco` and `Burrito` would get the `add_hot_sauce` method, but `Cereal` would not. However, examples of the Strategy pattern I've seen don't suggest or encourage doing multi-layer inheritance like this, but all of the examples have used just one layer of inheritance.

Is there any consensus or standard acceptable methods to tackle this issue?

Comment: Adding a subclass that the two other classes inherit from sounds like the best option for me. I don't see why it would be discouraged, it's totally acceptable. Another option would be to create a `module` that has that shared behaviour, and `include` it in the two classes only.

Comment: @TamerShlash Actually the `module` might be an even better idea. After digging into my example more and trying to add the middle subclass, I realized another class with a different middle class will also need to use the shared methods. Importing a `module` into each class would work out much better. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: [here](https://medium.com/aviabird/ruby-composition-over-inheritance-3ff786ad9e5d) is a nice post that may be very interest under this choices between inheritance and composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to expose the unused methods to the children at all, you should use modules for the individual behaviors

```
class FoodStrategies::Base
  def eat
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

module CanBeSpicy
  def add_hot_sauce
    puts "Food is now spicy"
  end
end

class FoodStrategies::Taco < FoodStrategies::Base
  include CanBeSpicy
  def eat
    add_hot_sauce
    puts "Spicy and delicious!"
  end
end

class FoodStrategies::Burrito < FoodStrategies::Base
  include CanBeSpicy
  def eat
    add_hot_sauce
    puts "Spicy and tasty!"
  end
end

class FoodStrategies::Cereal < FoodStrategies::Base
  def eat
    puts "Yum"
  end
end
```

If you have a bunch of behaviors to add, you can pass multiple like

```
include BehaviorA, BehaviorB
```

There are of course many other ways to do this, but I think in this case, although the modules approach might seem more rote because you have to manually specify the list of behaviors for each class instead of doing it in the parent, it's regardless the simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

There's more to inheritance than just calling methods in a superclass, you can also override:

```
class FoodStrategies::Cereal < FoodStrategies::Base
  def add_hot_sauce
    super
    raise FlagrantCulinaryError, "what is wrong with you"
  end
end
```

You *can* add hot sauce to cereal, and it would make it spicy. So `super` allows you to handle this *exceptional* case. For, example:

```
class Bob
  def eat food
    # Bob eats _everything_ with hot sauce!
    begin
      food.add_hot_sauce
    rescue FlagrantCulinaryError
      # and he doesn't care
    end
    food.eat
  end
end
```

In most cases you probably won't catch the exception, so the result will be functionally the same as if the method wasn't defined at all: an error.

If lots of subclasses have this exceptional behavior it isn't really exceptional anymore. Then you should probably introduce an intermediate class that separates foods to which hot sauce can be added.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I had to +1 it just for making me laugh - good on you sir. :)